# What does "[," mean in Python arguments?

Tags: python

What does "[, ]" mean in Python args? They can be seen in input arguments such as:

```
cv2.Canny(image, threshold1, threshold2[, edges[, apertureSize[, L2gradient]]])
```

or scikit-learn; (e.g sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression):

```
fit(X, y[, sample_weight])  Fit linear model.
```

What does y[, sample_weight] actually mean? Does it mean something like the first dimension in the array?

```
y[:,sample_weight]
```

Update:
Thanks for the answers, it means optional. But why are they nested though?

```
threshold2[, edges[, apertureSize[, L2gradient]]]
```

Comment: optional.......

Comment: Taking y[:,sample_weight] as an example, y is definitely not optional, so it means that the y could be either in 1 or 2 dimensions?

Comment: Thanks @KenY-N, that didn't show up when I tried to search

Comment: yes `y` is not optional, but `sample_weight` is. You see, the arguments inside square brackets are optional.